# Excel VBA Recordset QUestions

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, and I have a question:
1. I populate a listbox with the DEN field from recordset and I have also an textbox named tx1. When I move up and down in the list, i want to fill the textbox.text with the corresponding value of a record in that list
ex.:

```
DEN: Mary
CODE:M1
```

So, I want to retrieve "M1" in the text box. How can I do that?

Thanks!

```
Apppath
Dim j As Integer
Dim cna As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rsee As New ADODB.Recordset
cna.Open "ODBC;DSN=Firebird;Driver=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;Dbname=" & yserver & ":" & ycale & ydb & ";CHARSET=NONE;UID=SYSDBA; PWD=blank;Client=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\fbclient.dll"

cna.BeginTrans
rsee.Open "SELECT DEN, CODE from PROD order by DEN asc", cna, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic
cna.CommitTrans

If rsee.RecordCount > 0 Then
Me.lstProducts.ColumnCount = rsee.Fields.Count
j = 0
    rsee.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rsee.EOF
    Me.lstProdus.AddItem
    Me.lstProdus.List(j, 0) = rsee.Fields("DEN")
rsee.MoveNext
j = j + 1
Loop
End If
```

Comment: Use a DLOOKUP in your text box, based off the value in the listbox, or do the lookup in code

Comment: FYI, you don't need a loop to populate there - use: `Me.lstProdus.Column = rsee.GetRows`

Comment: DLOOKUP is not present in Excel VBA